# Change the name of the id field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In java Spring and under MongoDB i am creating the following field (id) of a class :

```
    @Id 
    public String _id;
```

in order to create the identifier field with the name _id but i get an indentifier id with the compilation warning :  `WARN 11916 --- [           main] o.s.d.m.c.m.BasicMongoPersistentProperty : Customizing field name for id property not allowed! Custom name will not be considered!`

My Question is how to change the name of the id field in java spring (if that's even possible)

EDIT : i tried with @Field("_id") but it's not working.

Thank you,

Comment: change it in your entity or in the mongodb?

Comment: change it when i fetch objects through Java (controllers) so the answer is in my entity

Comment: you cannot change the fields name in mongodb, you can name the property where the id is mapped onto whatever you want. Maybe you should elaborate more how you want to use your entity (code!)

Comment: @thst elaborate what ? everything is clear ! please leave this question to be answered by someone else you are not helpful here thanks !

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

The warning comes from MongoDB which is unhappy of an @Id field having a property name other than those supported by spring data based on the [root cause](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/11417144bd3574c35af06fde3a3c2e56a1dd5890/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/BasicMongoPersistentProperty.java#L85)

Based of the supported Id fields names stored in the Set `SUPPORTED_ID_PROPERTY_NAMES` includes {"id", "_id}.

That being said your naming of id field should be accepted which is apparently not. It may come from another document. You should check how many @Document you have.

Usually, a basic mongoDB document in Spring includes two main information:

1. The @Document annotation in the model object (e.g a User)
2. The @Id annotation from the id property in the model class

Here an example :

```
@Document
public class User {
     
     @Id
     private BigInteger id;

     // other fields
     /**
      * Returns the identifier of the document.
      * 
      * @return the id
     */
    public BigInteger getId() {
         return id;
    }

    // getters & setters for other fields (id have only a getter /!\)
}
```

What you described in your question description is more convenient for JPA based entity for SQL-databases and not suitable for MongoDB document.

Also, I encourage you to check Spring Data MongoDB project and this [sample project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-mongodb#samples) to see "best practice to start with" when creating such projects

Comment: THIS DEFINITELY NOT AN ANSWER TO MY QUESTION

Comment: actually this is a helpful answer to a possible interpretation of your question.

Comment: @lopmkipm I will leave you to find someone to answer your question. The fact alone that two helpful members tried to give advice and were not clear how to support you in what you want to achieve, should give you something to think about. Good luck

Comment: totally unnecessary comment that also should be downgraded (if anything is still unclear you should state this in a polite comment not like you did)

Comment: Check my edit it contains more information to better understand the warning and how to deal with.